Transparent mesh on Edit Mode
Well, I updated Blender to 4.1 and when I enter on Eidt Mode to start modeling ocurrs this:

Note that X-Ray and Wireframe are turned off and if I click anywhere in the scene it becomes normal. How can I fix it? It's really annoying! Thanks for help.

Haven't seen that one before. Check that you have the latest GPU drivers installed.

You may want to report this directly to blender.  In Blender go to Help - Report a Bug

@RickT I imagined it might be that...
